# How to structure my java packages

Tags: java, packages, hierarchy

I have a Java library, quite a huge one.

I'm asking regarding Best Practices of structuring the source.

For example, the logging sybsystem:

Option 1: All in one package, named to sort nicely

- Log - static accessor
- LogMonitor - interface for log minotor
- LogMonitorBase - abstract class
- LogMonitorStdout - print log to console
- LogWriter - interface for file logger
- LogWriterSimple - log writer with just one log file
- LogWriterArchiving - log writer that handles old log files

Option 2: Subpackages for Monitors and Writers, with better names

- Log
- monitors/LogMonitor
- monitors/BaseMonitor
- monitors/StdoutMonitor
- writers/LogWriter
- writers/SimpleLog
- writers/ArchivingLog

The second maybe looks better, but perhaps it's not so practical from the java point of view (two extra packages).

What do you suggest as the best practice here? A lot in one package, grouped by naming prefixes, or a lot of subpackages with better names?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: then what do you suggest? I've seen the java api packages are super messy, all in one package. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Things that are almost always used together should be together.

Comment: questions about "the way to go" have been asked and answered before, see [How to divide OO project into packages?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/238606/31260) "In terms of guidelines you could start with SOLID and Packaging Principles..." and [What are the steps to grouping related classes into packages](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/216765/31260) "developers are expected to package at their discretion, following the general guidance and ideas provided by conventions...  The goal is to make reading and understanding the code easier..."